# Create Ruby instance variable to default based off of other instance variable values

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I am creating a Ruby class that takes a hash as an argument:

```
class Player
include PlayerHelper
attr_accessor :at_bats, :hits, :walks, :hbp, :sac_flies, :singles, :doubles,
              :triples, :hr, :put_outs, :assists, :errors, :er, :ip, :so,
              :stolen_bases, :caught_stealing
def initialize(hash)
  @at_bats = hash.fetch(:at_bats, nil)
  @hits = hash.fetch(:hits, nil)
  @walks = hash.fetch(:walks, nil)
  @hbp = hash.fetch(:hbp, nil)
  @sac_flies = hash.fetch(:sac_flies, nil)
  @singles = hash.fetch(:singles, nil)
  @doubles = hash.fetch(:doubles, nil)
  @triples = hash.fetch(:triples, nil)
  @hr = hash.fetch(:hr, nil)
  @put_outs = hash.fetch(:put_outs, nil)
  @assists = hash.fetch(:assists, nil)
  @errors = hash.fetch(:errors, nil)
  @er = hash.fetch(:er, nil)
  @ip = hash.fetch(:ip, nil)
  @walks = hash.fetch(:walks, nil)
  @hits = hash.fetch(:hits, nil)
  @so = hash.fetch(:so, nil)
  @stolen_bases = hash.fetch(:stolen_bases, nil)
  @caught_stealing = hash.fetch(:caught_stealing, nil)
end
```

I want to give the user the option of including :`singles` and first check if `:singles` was included in the hash. If so, give it the hash's value. This part I have working.

What I can't get to work is to give @`singles` the value of `:hits - (:doubles + :triples + :hr)` if the :`singles` key doesn't exist. I have tried making a separate method to call initially, but this doesn't seem to work.

How can I set the value of `@singles` based off of the other hash values if there was no `:singles` key included?

Comment: "this doesn't seem to work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "this doesn't **seem** to work"? Does it work or doesn't it work? Please, also make sure that have actually provided a [mcve]. In your case, I highly doubt that your example is minimal, I am pretty sure it does *not* require 26 lines to demonstrate your problem. Also, your example is not complete, it is missing the definition of `PlayerHelper`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to iterate the hash? `hash.each { |k, v| public_send("#{k}=", v) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the second argument of the `fetch` method can be used for:

```
def initialize(hash)
  # ...
  @hits = hash.fetch(:hits, nil)
  @doubles = hash.fetch(:doubles, nil)
  @triples = hash.fetch(:triples, nil)
  @hr = hash.fetch(:hr, nil)
  @singles = hash.fetch(:singles, @hits - (@doubles + @tripples + @hr))
  # ...
end
```

However, note that since you are defaulting all values to `nil`, you could hit `undefined method on nil:NilClass`-type errors if those values are not passed into the constructor! You may wish to set some different defaults, or make them required arguments...

Answer (score 1):

Use `||=` which is the syntax sugar for `neu = neu || old`, setting the new value if and only it was not set before (equals `nil`.)

```
ALL = %i[
  at_bats hits walks hbp sac_flies singles
  doubles triples hr put_outs assists errors
  er ip so stolen_bases caught_stealing
]

attr_accessor *ALL

def initialize(hash) do
  ALL.each do |iv|
    instance_variable_set("@{iv}", hash.fetch(iv, nil))
  end

  #        ⇓⇓⇓ set if and only it was not set previously 
  @singles ||= @hits - (@doubles + @triples + @hr)
end
```

Comment: `NameError`, no local variable named `all` in `initialize`.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the help